# Array replacement javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have two array:

> array1 = [35,433]; 
>  array2 = [70,154,73];

Need to be arrays :

> result[0] = [35,70]; 
>  result[1] = [35,154]; 
>  result[2] =
>   [35,73]; 
>  result[3] = [433,70]; 
>  result[4] = [433,154];
>   result[5] = [433,73];

My code:

```js
var groupAttribute = [];
    groupAttribute[0] = ['35'=>'bla','433'=>'blu'];
    groupAttribute[1] = ['70'=>'fre','154'=>'nuy','73'=>'tres'];
var counter = 0;
var countAttributes = 5;
var combinat = [];
for (var i = 0, j = 0;; j++) {
    if (i >= groupAttribute.length && j >= countAttributes) {
     break;
    }
    if (i >= groupAttribute.length) {
     i = 0;
    }
   combinat[counter] = [];
    $.each(groupAttribute[i],function(key, attribute) {  
     combinat[counter].push(parseInt(key));
     counter++;
     i++;
    });
            
}
console.log(combinat);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Pls help me

Comment: `['35'=>'bla']` is not a valid synat for Javascript array.

Comment: You're getting answers for a fixed number of arrays. Is that what you need, or does it need to work with any number of arrays?

Comment: @rockstar  Yes,  it need to work with any number of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a purely function/recursive solution that works with any positive number of arrays.

```js
let array1 = [35, 433];
let array2 = [70, 154, 73];
let array3 = [1, 2, 3];

let result = combine(array1, array2, array3 /* more arrays */ );

function combine(arr, ...rest) {
    if (!rest.length) return arr.map(n => [n]);

    const sub = combine(...rest);
    return arr.reduce((a, n) => [...a, ...sub.map(a2 => [n, ...a2])], [])
}

console.log(result);
```

---

For the matrix diff you asked about in the comment, do this:

```js
var arr1 = [[35,70],[433,70],[35,73],[433,73],[35,154],[433,154]];
var arr2 = [[433,70],[433,154],[433,73],[35,154]];

var result = [
  ...aNotInB(arr1, arr2),
  ...aNotInB(arr2, arr1),
];

function aNotInB(a, b) {
  return a.filter(([x, y]) => 
    !b.some(([x2, y2]) => x == x2 && y == y2)
  )
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: **Thank you very much**
How diff 2 matrix?
arr1 = [[35,70],[433,70],[35,73],[433,73],[35,154],[433,154]]
arr2 = [[433,70],[433,154],[433,73],[35,154]]
Need get:
res = [[35,70],[35,73]]
My code:
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  res = arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
}
But it didnt work

Comment: @YevheniyAntikov: I added a solution to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two separated array

```js
var array1 = [35,433];
var array2 = [70,154,73];

var newArr = [];

array1.forEach(function(a) {
  array2.forEach(function(b) {
    newArr.push([a, b])
  })
})

console.log(newArr)
```

If nested depth is unknown:

```js
var arr = [[35,433], [70,154,73], [5,1]];

function Permute(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr[0];
  }
  
  var res = [];
  var sliced = Permute(arr.slice(1));
  
  arr[0].forEach(function(a) {
    sliced.forEach(function(b) {
      res.push([a].concat(b))
    })
  })
 
  return res;
}

var newArr = Permute(arr);
console.log(newArr)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, thanks, but if i have three arrays, what can i do? var array1 = [35,433]; var array2 = [70,154]; var array3 = [5,1]; and i need res[0]= [35,70,5];res[1]=[35,154,5];res[2]=[35,70,1];res[3]=[35,154,‌​1];res[4]= [433,70,5];res[5]=[433,154,5];res[6]=[433,70,1];res[7]=[433,‌​154,1];

Comment: Add one more loop.

Comment: Yes, but if i need to work with undetermined number of arrays?

Comment: @YevheniyAntikov added recursive function